# Adding a control to another control which is created at runtime

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a picturebox control to a panel which is created at runtime.
It is for a chess game I am working on.  I want to add a picture box to each panel , an assigning the image to the control later.  Here is what I have so far:

```
//Sets the number of rows on the chess board
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)         
{ 
    //Set the number of columns on the board
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)     
    {
        ChessSquare sq = new ChessSquare(((char)(65 + i)).ToString(), 7- j);
        sq.Color = (i + (j % 2)) % 2 == 0 ? Color.Black : Color.White;

        Panel p = new Panel()
        {
            Size = new Size(blockSize, blockSize),
            BackColor = sq.Color,
            Tag = sq,
            Location = new Point(blockSize * i + 15, blockSize * j + 15),
            BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
        };
        p.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(squareMouseEnter);
        p.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(squareMouseLeave);
        p.Click += new EventHandler(squareMouseClick);

        chessBoardPanels[i, j] = p;
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(p);
    }
}
//SetUp Board
SetUpBoad Setup = new SetUpBoad();
SetUpBoad(chessBoardPanels);
```

Comment: What is your question, and what problems have you encountered so far?  Compiler errors?  Runtime errors?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already put the `Panels` into the panel-array (?)

```
chessBoardPanels[i, j] = p;
```

You can add the `PictureBoxes` either now or later..:

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox ();
pb.Size = ..
pb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

chessBoardPanels[i,j].Controls.Add(pb);
```

To access them later you can cast their first `Control` to `PictureBox`:

```
PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)chessBoardPanels[i,j].Controls[0];
pb.Image = aQueenImage;
```

If you want to add a `PictureBox` only where a piece is you need to do checks:

```
if (chessBoardPanels[i,j].Controls.Count > 0)
{
   PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)chessBoardPanels[i,j].Controls[0];
   pb.Image = aQueenImage;
}
```

To move a piece from `<i1,j1>` to `<i2, j2>` you do as expected:

```
chessBoardPanels[i1,j1].Controls[0].Parent = chessBoardPanels[i2,j2];
```

I notice that you are hooking up mouse events. If you want to use them to move the pieces, remember that **transparency will not work for overlapping controls** in Winforms and so while a piece-Box is crossing `Panels` it will not have working tranparency around the `Image`.

While the pBox is nested in a Panel all is well but to move it you would have to first make it a child of the parent of those panels and only add it to the target `Panel` upon `MouseUp`; the coordinate corrections can be solved but the tranparency, if you need it, will be a bigger problem..

The usual advice it to consider `drawing` at least those board squares and maybe even the pieces onto a base board-`Panel` (or board-`PictureBox`)